# Repositioning element on scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reposition an element on scroll using jQuery scroll event and just adjusting margin-top property.Element is inside bootstrap nav so its showed along all other elements inside nav on desktop and for mobiles its just fixed positioned in upper left corner.element contains two flag links for different page languages.
My code is:
Html:

```
<div class="navbar yamm navbar-default">
    <div class="flags">
        <a href="#" class="flag-link-fiverr"><img src="UK_flag.png" alt="English"></a>
        <a href="#" class="flag-link-fiverr"><img src="DK_flag.png" alt="Danish"></a>
    </div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
....
```

js:

```
var scrollingDiv = $(".flags").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();


    $(window).scroll(function(){

            if(scrollingDiv > 100) {
                $(".flags").css("margin-top", "24px");
            }

            if(scrollingDiv == 92) {
                $(".flags").css("margin-top", "10px");
            }



            console.log(scrollingDiv);


    });
```

console log displays always 92 as its position.One note page contains 1 more navigation which is above bootstrap nav so I need this margin-top fix for that.Whan nav goes down it reposition itself nicely,but whan it comes back it keeps margin-top property at 10px and flags jump out of aligment.
Thanks for all future ansers :)

Comment: Also I have tryed with < 100 for second if statement,but somehow it just wont work...

Comment: It whould be nice if somebody could tell me is it even possible to solve it this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `var scrollingDiv = $(".flags").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();` this inside you're `$(window).scroll(function(){});`

When you declare it like its current state. The `scrollingDiv` will keep `92px` because it only sets it on page load.

If inside the `scroll()` function, it will update the `value` when the user is scrolling.

**Small Demo (I dont know you're actual layout)**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    
      var scrollingDiv = $(".flags").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

            if(scrollingDiv > 100) {
                $(".flags").css("margin-top", "24px");
            }

            if(scrollingDiv >= 92 && scrollingDiv < 100) {
                $(".flags").css("margin-top", "10px");
            }



            console.log(scrollingDiv);


    });
```

```css
.scroll-container {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroll-container .flags {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="flags">
        <a href="#" class="flag-link-fiverr"><img src="UK_flag.png" alt="English"></a>
        <a href="#" class="flag-link-fiverr"><img src="DK_flag.png" alt="Danish"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It solves the issue with logging, but still whan I scroll it back up it doesnt change the margin-top back to 24px...This was a good insight,its just that it still wont behave as it should.Thanks for this anser,helpfull one :)

Comment: See fiddle. `92px` specific is very hard to archieve. Because the scrollbars dont scroll per pixel.

Comment: Basicly thats it,its just that whan I scroll back to top it still logs 10 as offset top and its bigger(visualy).Guessing it cant be fixed for some wierd reason...Thanks for help anyway:)